# Bootstrap spinner overlay form (not whole page)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to have bootstrap spinner that is on top of the form (it overlays form). However, the only thing I was able to get is to overlay the whole page. I am using Bootstrap.

```
<style>
    .overlay {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1000;
        top: 40%;
        left: 0px;
        opacity: 0.5;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    }
</style>

<div class="overlay" id="loading" >
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="spinner-border" role="status" >
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="num">Enter number <span>?</span></label>
        <input id="num" type="text" class="form-control"/>
       
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Check </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U should put the spinner inside your form like this

```
<form method="post">
  <div class="overlay" id="loading" >
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="spinner-border" role="status" >
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <fieldset disabled>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="num">Enter number <span>?</span></label>
      <input id="num" type="text" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Check </button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

then give the spinner an absolute position

```
form {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: The top and left CSS properties give the X/Y coordinates where the top left corner (or top right corner in rtl dir) of your element should be. If you want the spinner to be truly centered, you need to add a `transform` property with `translate(-50%, -50%);` so that it gets X = 50% minus half of its width and Y = 50% minus half of its height

Comment: Ki Jey I think I didn't get what is the problem with answer above?

Comment: @renathy U`ll see what he means if u grow the spinner, I'll update my answer

Comment: I see, I fixed that. Maybe you also can suggest how to make form disabled or not clickable when loader appears? Currently ti is clickable

Comment: Wrap the input group into a `<fieldset>` and give it the disabled attribute. @renathy